# ListView is empty when popping from backstack

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I  have been stuck on this problem for quite some time now.I have a ListView with a custom ListView Adapter. When I click on an item it opens up a Webview fragment. Its all fine till there, however when I pop the WebView fragment the ListView turns up to be empty. According to my understanding the ListView should have stayed the way as it was when i had added it to the backtrace . Here's my adding a fragment code and the onBackPress function.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

and

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//  finish();
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 1 || count==0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

    }

}
```

For example one of my Fragment classes is like this :

```
public static class PreferencesFragment extends Fragment {


    public PreferencesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override       
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        vfrag= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preferences, container, false);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)vfrag.findViewById(R.id.swipe);           
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);     

            }
        });
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);


        return vfrag;
    }


}
```

If you want to take a look at my complete code here's the [link](http://pastebin.ca/3196855). As a sidenote, I have gone through many of the questions here at SO on this topic but none of the answers solved my problem. I would be very grateful if someone helps me out on this one,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting your fragment's `setRetainInstance(true)` in the onCreate method of your fragment with the list view? It'd be super helpful if you could pick out the bit of relevant code instead of linking that huge pastebin.

Comment: Added a fragment class @jyanks

Comment: So in the fragment's onResume code, you need to be reinstantiating that adapter, since it will get recycled in the onPause. It might be beneficial to just recall the async task from the onResume method?

Comment: Tried the setRetainInstance(true) in the onCreateView but it didnt work.

Comment: Also I dont want to recall the async task as it will take some time to load @jyanks

Comment: Then you need to implement some sort of cache on the client (maybe a database or flat file) where you can recall the data quickly.